Adding SD or SEM to the following graph
I am trying to make a strip plot and need to add the STD or SEM to the bar graphs. I have every thing working.
Currently using the following which gives me everything I want except for the STD/SEM bars.
ggplot(da_results, aes(x=ident, y=logFC))+
  geom_beeswarm(data = ~ filter(da_results, abs(P) < 0.9), color = "gray",cex = 0.2) +
  geom_beeswarm(aes(color = ident), data = ~ filter(da_results, abs(P) >= lim),cex = 0.2) +
  geom_bar(aes(color = ident), data = ~ filter(da_results, abs(P) >= lim),stat = "summary",alpha=0.5) +
  coord_flip()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+geom_hline(yintercept = 0)


Hi user23595218, welcome to SO. It is important to provide a minimal, reproducible example when asking a question. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks

Here is an example of how to add error bars to a bar plot that also includes geom_beeswarm() using an example dataset.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)

mpg_sd <- mpg %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(hwy, na.rm = TRUE),
            SD = sd(hwy, na.rm = TRUE),
            lower = Mean - SD,
            upper = Mean + SD)

ggplot() +
  geom_beeswarm(data = mpg,
                aes(x = class, y = hwy),
                shape = 21, fill = 'white') +
  geom_bar(data = mpg_sd,
           aes(x = class, y = Mean, fill = class),
           stat = 'identity',
           alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(data = mpg_sd,
                aes(x = class, ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
                color = 'black',
                width = 0.2) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')


Created on 2024-06-07 with reprex v2.1.0
